# Android Alert dialog closes without waiting

Tags: android

In my app i used an alert dialog to display warning message and wait for yes/no.  But alert dialog display without waiting and disappears.  Here the code shown below

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Delete Macro");
            builder.setMessage(" " + mMacroName + "\n\nAre you sure ?");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // some tasks
                   }
               });

            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       finish();
                   }
               });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            builder.show();
```

**logcat received** shows some leakage

```
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279): Activity com.mtxlabs.hat.setup.MacroProp has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43ea4d50 that was originally added here
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mtxlabs.hat.setup.MacroProp has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43ea4d50 that was originally added here
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at com.mtxlabs.hat.setup.MacroProp.onSaveButtonClick(MacroProp.java:218)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 04-02 15:09:32.954: E/WindowManager(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Comment: Problem is on MacroProp.java at line No. 218

Comment: At #218 is builder.show();

Comment: The dialog doesn't wait if you don't wait! So you must make sure that after `show()` you are not doing anything else that might result in a start/close of an activity.

Comment: your code is doing something when you show alert dialog. thats why its give you has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow. so you have to check mannually..

Comment: see my code below and remove the finish() from negative button ...see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Delete Macro");
                builder.setMessage(" " + mMacroName + "\n\nAre you sure ?");

                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // some tasks
                       }
                   })

                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                       //you are finishing the activity first and trying to display          the dialog later.this your problem 
                           // comment the `finish()`    and see

                          //finish();
                       }
                   }).create();

                builder.show();
```

Comment: my working code is same like your code..then i don't know y its not working